# Tricky SQL Query for rolling credits

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an sql query that is baffling me, basically I've credits table where credits can be applied and deducted, simple, it gets tricky when I introduce expiry dates for applied credits as I've to almost rollover dates, the basic table is below:

```
CreditID     int
Credit       int
AppliedDate  DateTime
ExpiryDate   DateTime
```

An example of the data entry is below:

```
CredidID | Credit | AppliedDate | ExpiryDate
---------+--------+-------------+-----------
1        | 10     |             | 1/8/2017       (10 credit added that expire)
2        | 10     |             | 1/1/2018       (10 credit added that expire)
3        | -5     | 1/9/2017    |                (5 credits used on 1/9)
```

So the answer for this is my current credits, 5, but as the table gets more complex I can't think of an sql query that would give me today's credit balance at any given time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You don't store when credits were added? Only when they expire? So we can only deduct from the IDs that the credits in the two first rows were added on or before 2017-09-01 (or 2017-01-09? which is it?). Correct? So if the third date were 1/7/2017 instead, then we would have taken the five from the first credit and now have 10 remaining from the second. Yes?

Comment: Anyway. That doesn't sound like a task for SQL at all. Use a programming language.

Comment: Hi, i am using mssql 2012, i am storing AppliedDate against the deductions and expiry date against the credits, sorry if this isnt clear

Comment: Hi Thorston, i did come up with a solution using Linq, i just thought if i could use a stored procedure it may be quicker, maybe my use of Linq is correct but i like to use sql if possible for complicated queries

Comment: Its not likely to get to this level but if this table had 1000000 records then effectively i would have to iterate through every row to build up a balance, just cant think of a simple solution which is frustrating me?

Comment: LINQ? Wow. The task sounds so complicated. Everytime you use credits, you'd subtract them from the credit bucket(s) with the closest expiry date that still have credit left. If you have a working algorithm in LINQ, though, then it should be possible to convert it to SQL.

Comment: Is there ever an applied date with a positive Credit value? How do credits get added in this table? Is the order of when things happened (credits added, credits applied) based on the CreditID? So there were 20 credits added (date unknown), 10 expired on 1/8/17, 5 were applied on 1/9/17. That (date unknown) part is odd.

Comment: I think you will have to iterate through every row anyway. How else do you do it in LINQ? I think you must read record by record and with every deduction look from which credit to remove it.

Comment: Have you tried this (where YOURDATE is the date you want to filter for)? SELECT SUM(Credit) FROM Table WHERE (ExpiryDate >= YOURDATE and  AppliedDate is null) or (ExpiryDate is null and AppliedDate <= YOURDATE)

Comment: @nicogen: Easy to calculate. As one of the two dates is always null, the criteria in `WHERE` is never met, so the sum will be null :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks! I updated the comment to reflect what you correctly said!

Comment: @nicogen: Unfortunately it is not that easy. See my comments above. If the deduction date were 1/7/2017 instead of 1/9/2017 then the five would have been taken from the first credit instead of the second and we'd have ten credits now instead of five. Both 1/7/2017 and 1/9/2017 are in the past, but one is before first credit expired, the other afterwards.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are right! Unfortunately I have to give up and get back to work :-) :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts, i think its confirmed that is actually a tricky setup, i think the only solution for speed is to store the credits in a single property and update as i go with a trigger to deduct expired credits on a daily basis

Answer (score 1):

If I'd have to do it by database (only if I'd have to ;) ), I'd do two tables, one with balance, second with a single credits operation.

For example (in MSSQL):

```
create table WalletBalance
(
    WalletID bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    LastModifiedTime datetime,
    Balance bigint
)

create table CreditsOperation
(
    ID bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    WalletID bigint,
    ExpirationDate date,
    ModifiedTime datetime

    foreign key (WalletID) references WalletBalance(WalletID)
)
```

Then make a trigger for update, delete and insert for operations table, which would add or subtract wallet balance.

Then - I'd do a daily SQL job which would exec procedure for checking expiration date etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(credit) +  (select isnull(sum(credit),0) from credits 
        where AppliedDate is not null 
        and AppliedDate > 
                    (select isnull(max(ExpiryDate),0) from Credits 
                    where ExpiryDate < getdate() and ExpiryDate is not null)) 
'Credit Balance'
    from credits where ExpiryDate > getdate() and ExpiryDate is not null
```

Logic- 
1. get the sum of deducted credits later than the applied credits(applied credits that are expired  i.e.

Sum of this (1+2) would desired result ( summing the above result since carries the negative value in the table )

Let me know if you still failing any case.

Comment: Hi Vijay, this almost works, and does in most cases, it falls down when an expired credit is only partially used up, 

ie 
12 credits expires on 1/8 (now expired but only 6 were used)
6 credits used on 1/7 
12 credits expires on 1/10
= 12 credits available today (script says 18 as it still thinks 1st credit was valid?)

Comment: small modification in the query to handle all scenarios.

Comment: select sum(credit) +  (select isnull(sum(credit),0) from credits 
        where AppliedDate is not null 
        and AppliedDate > 
                    (select isnull(max(ExpiryDate),0) from Credits 
                    where ExpiryDate < getdate() and ExpiryDate is not null)) 
'Credit Balance'
    from credits where ExpiryDate > getdate() and ExpiryDate is not null

Answer (score 0):

If your applied credits are always negative and in the past you can use:

```
SELECT SUM(t.Credit) FROM [yourtable] t 
WHERE ExpiryDate IS NULL OR ExpiryDate > GetDate()
```

Comment: No. Let's say in the last years you had a total of 1000 credits of which you used 900 and the other 100 expired. The only credit you have left is a credit of 50 expiring next year. You'd calculate 50 - 900 = -850, where you should get between 0 to 50, depending on whether there have been deductions from this credit.